# Download service doesn't triggers itself after certain period of runs

Tags: android, service, android-alarms, android-wake-lock

I have an app which uses service to first get user location using Network provider and then when location is found, launch downloading task to get data and put them into notification. My problem is that when I turn the screen off, the services launches about 3 times and then nothing happens. This only happens when phone is not connected to pc. Here is my source code for service and my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="sk.digitale.wazenotificator" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".NotificationService" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="Downloading data"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the code for service:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
static String updateOnWifi;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
String url;
String firstEventDescription = "";
String secondEventDescription = "";
String mp3Link = "false";
static int NOTIFICATION = 10002;
static NotificationManager nManager;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean vibrate;
boolean updateWiFi;
boolean updateMe;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
double latitude;
double longitude;
LocationManager lm;
int radius;
String email;
static PendingIntent pi;
static AlarmManager am;
boolean run;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNjfdhotDimScreen");
    wl.acquire();
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    radius = sharedpreferences.getInt("Radius", 2);
    email = sharedpreferences.getString("Email", "dummy@gmail.com");
    url = sharedpreferences.getString("url", "specific url");
    Log.d("tag", "new url " + url);
    int updateInterval = sharedpreferences.getInt("UpdateTimeout", 20);
    updateWiFi = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Wifi", true);
    vibrate = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Vibrate", true);
    run = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Running", true);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i1 = new Intent(NotificationService.this, NotificationService.class);
    pi = PendingIntent.getService(NotificationService.this, 123, i1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (run) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, updateInterval);
        new getLocationdTask().execute();
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    } else {
        am.cancel(pi);
        stopSelf();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void showNotification() {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    String provider = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(NotificationService.this);
    Notification n;
    if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase("no connection")) {
        n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Waze Watchdog")
                .setContentText("No connection")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setOngoing(true).build();
    } else {
        n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Waze Watchdog")
                .setContentText(firstEventDescription)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setOngoing(true).build();
    }
    nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, n);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    if (nManager != null) {
        nManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
    }
}

private class getLocationdTask extends AsyncTask implements LocationListener {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("tag", "Get location onPreExecute");
        lm = (LocationManager) NotificationService.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            if (run) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                showNotification();
            } else {
                if (nManager != null) {
                    nManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (run) {
                Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                } else {
                    latitude = 48.17;
                    longitude = 17.13;
                }
                new DownloadJSON().execute();
                showNotification();
            } else {
                if (nManager != null) {
                    nManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
                }
            }
        }
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("tag", "Lat: " + String.valueOf(latitude) + " Lon: " + String.valueOf(longitude));
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        String abc = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(NotificationService.this);
        Log.d("Tag", "provider: " + abc);
        //appendLog("actual provider: " + abc);
        if ((abc.equalsIgnoreCase("mobile") || updateWiFi) && run) {
            updateMe = true;
            showNotification();
        } else {
            updateMe = false;
            if (nManager != null) {
                nManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
            }
        }
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (updateMe) {
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            JSONObject jsonobject;
            if (radius == 100) {
                Log.d("tag","radius == 100");
                if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("custom url")) {
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url + "?radius=" + String.valueOf(radius) + "&account=" + String.valueOf(email));
                } else {
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url +"&radius=" + String.valueOf(radius) + "&account=" + String.valueOf(email));
                }
            } else {
                if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("custom url")) {
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url + "?lat=" + String.valueOf(latitude) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(longitude) + "&radius=" + String.valueOf(radius) + "&account=" + String.valueOf(email));
                } else {
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url + "&lat=" + String.valueOf(latitude) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(longitude) + "&radius=" + String.valueOf(radius) + "&account=" + String.valueOf(email));
                }
            }
            if (jsonobject == null) {
                url = sharedpreferences.getString("url", "custom url");
            } else {
                try {
                    firstEventDescription = jsonobject.getString("text");
                    if (firstEventDescription.equalsIgnoreCase(secondEventDescription)) {
                        firstEventDescription = secondEventDescription;
                    } else {
                        secondEventDescription = firstEventDescription;
                    }
                    url = jsonobject.getString("url");
                    mp3Link = jsonobject.getString("mp3");
                    Log.d("Tag", "url from server: " + url + " Notification display: " + firstEventDescription);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        Vibrator c = (Vibrator) NotificationService.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        c.vibrate(750);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("url", url);
        editor.apply();
        if (run) {
            showNotification();
        } else if (nManager != null) {
            nManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
        }
        if (!mp3Link.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            /*if (vibrate) {
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) NotificationService.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(750);
            }*/
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NotificationService.this, Uri.parse(mp3Link));
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            mp3Link = "false";
        }
        if (wl != null) {
            Log.v("TAG", "Releasing wakelock");
            try {
                wl.release();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "Wakelock reference is null");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
int step = 1;
int max = 600;
int min = 20;
int stepRadius = 1;
int maxRadius = 100;
int minRadius = 2;
int updateInterval;
int radiusValue;
static boolean isRunning = true;
String email = "dummy@gmail.com";
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    getEmail();
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    CheckBox activate = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Activate);
    isRunning = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Running", true);
    if (isRunning) {
        activate.setChecked(true);
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class));
    }
    activate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                //Case 1
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                isRunning = true;
                editor.putBoolean("Running", true);
                editor.putString("Email", email);
                editor.commit();
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class));
            } else {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class));

                if (NotificationService.nManager != null) {
                    NotificationService.nManager.cancel(NotificationService.NOTIFICATION);
                }
                if(NotificationService.am!=null&&NotificationService.pi!=null){
                    NotificationService.am.cancel(NotificationService.pi);
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                isRunning=false;
                editor.putBoolean("Running", false);
                editor.putString("url", "http://5.9.44.5/waze/appjson.php");
                editor.commit();
            }
            //case 2

        }
    });
    final CheckBox updateOnWiFi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.UpdateOnWiFi);
    boolean wifi = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Wifi", true);
    if (wifi) {
        updateOnWiFi.setChecked(true);
    }
    updateOnWiFi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                //Case 1
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Wifi", true);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Wifi", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
            //case 2

        }
    });
    CheckBox vibration = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Vibrations);
    boolean vibrate = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Vibrate", true);
    if (vibrate) {
        vibration.setChecked(true);
    }
    vibration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                //Case 1
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Vibrate", true);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Vibrate", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
            //case 2

        }
    });
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IntervalTime);
    final TextView radiusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radiusValue);
    SeekBar radius = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.radius);
    radius.setMax((maxRadius - minRadius) / stepRadius);
    radiusValue = sharedpreferences.getInt("Radius", 2);
    if (radiusValue == 100) {
        radiusText.setText("Everything");
    } else {
        radiusText.setText(String.valueOf(radiusValue) + "km");
    }
    radius.setProgress(radiusValue);
    radius.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            radiusValue = minRadius + (progress * stepRadius);
            if (radiusValue == 100) {
                radiusText.setText("Everything");
            } else {
                radiusText.setText(String.valueOf(radiusValue) + "km");
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("Radius", radiusValue);
            editor.apply();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    SeekBar interval = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.interval);
    interval.setMax((max - min) / step);
    updateInterval = sharedpreferences.getInt("UpdateTimeout", 20);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(updateInterval) + "s");
    interval.setProgress(updateInterval);
    interval.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            updateInterval = min + (progress * step);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(updateInterval) + "s");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("UpdateTimeout", updateInterval);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
}

public void getEmail() {
    AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
    for (Account account : list) {
        if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")) {
            if (arrayAdapter != null) {
                email = account.name;
                Log.d("Tag", account.name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code on wichi you bind the service to your context? Happened to me a couple of times that I bind the service to an Activity, and when the activity is on background, the service stops without any reason

Comment: Hi, well I don't bind my service. I just start it, but I can post my MainActivity code, see edit please